# Update a boolean field as criteria using Count inside IF

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have 2 tables called `t_task` and `t_task_details` in MS Access

`t_task` has 3 columns: `task_id`, `task_description`, `task_status` (`task_status` column is Yes/No column while the rest are Short Text)

`t_task_details` also has 3 columns: `task_id`, `task_date` and `done` (`done` is also Yes/No)

Every `task` is linked to `task_details` via `task_id`.

I want update `task_status` to Yes / True if **ALL** `task_details.done` are Yes / True

I have tried this, but unfortunately it's not working:

```
UPDATE t_task 
INNER JOIN t_task_details ON t_task.task_id = t_task_details.id
SET t_task.task_status = IIF(Count(t_task_details.done) = 0, True, False)
WHERE t_task_details.done = False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use a query like this:

```
UPDATE t_task
SET t_task.task_status = true
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) 
       FROM   t_task_details 
       WHERE  t_task_details.task_id = t_task.id) =
      (SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM   t_task_details
       WHERE  t_task_details.task_id = t_task.id
         AND  t_task_details.done = True)
```

I don't test it yet.

Note that this will update status of tasks that has no any details, If you want to remove them from update you can add this to the query:

```
 ...
         AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM t_task_details 
                    WHERE t_task_details.task_id = t_task.id);
```

**UPDATE :**
If you want to update status to false for other records, I suggest you to use this query instead:

```
UPDATE t_task
SET t_task.task_status = IIF(
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM   t_task_details 
     WHERE  t_task_details.task_id = t_task.id) =
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM   t_task_details
     WHERE  t_task_details.task_id = t_task.id
       AND  t_task_details.done = True), true, false)
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM t_task_details 
             WHERE t_task_details.task_id = t_task.id);
```

Comment: if all `t_task_details.done` true, `t_task.task_status` will turn to true as expected, but there is one problem, i want if there is **one or more** `t_task_details` is `false` the `t_task.task_status` turn to `false` as welli

Comment: I tried your updated code, however it doesn't work, an error appear:
"Operation must use an updateable query"

Answer (score 1):

You can also use DCount and DSum:

```
UPDATE 
    t_task 
SET 
    t_task.task_status =     
    (DCount("*", "t_task_details", "[task_id] = " & t_task.id & "") = 
    Abs(DSum("[done]","t_task_details", "[task_id] = " & t_task.id & "")))
```

If key is not numeric:

```
    (DCount("*", "t_task_details", "[task_id] = '" & t_task.id & "'") = 
    Abs(DSum("[done]","t_task_details", "[task_id] = '" & t_task.id & "'")))
```

Comment: this not work error, something like invalid conversion

Comment: It does work (tested here) if your key is numeric. If not, use modified code.